# Parallelize python for-loop

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I would like to parallelize the following python loop using a Mac Pro with 2 Quad-Core processors.

```
result_list = []
for a in a_range:
    for b in b_range:
        for c in c_range:
            result = call_fortran_program(a, b, c)
            result_list.append(result)
```

In my searches I've run across terms like Cython and GIL but it's still not clear to me on how to proceed.

Comment: Shouldn't `result_list.append(result)` follow your `result =` statement? Otherwise there would be only one result.

Answer (score 5):

```
from itertools import product
from multiprocessing import Pool

with Pool(processes=4) as pool:  # assuming Python 3
    pool.starmap(print, product(range(2), range(3), range(4)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor)

This can circumvent GIL lock by creating multiple processes.

An example from the website:

```
import concurrent.futures
import math

PRIMES = [
    112272535095293,
    112582705942171,
    112272535095293,
    115280095190773,
    115797848077099,
    1099726899285419]

def is_prime(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return False

    sqrt_n = int(math.floor(math.sqrt(n)))
    for i in range(3, sqrt_n + 1, 2):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

def main():
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for number, prime in zip(PRIMES, executor.map(is_prime, PRIMES)):
            print('%d is prime: %s' % (number, prime))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **asyncio**. (Documentation can be found [here][1]). It is used as a foundation for multiple Python asynchronous frameworks that provide high-performance network and web-servers, database connection libraries, distributed task queues, etc. Plus it has both high-level and low-level APIs to accomodate any kind of problem.

```
import asyncio

def background(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(None, f, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapped

@background
def your_function(argument):
    #code
```

Now this function will be run in parallel whenever called without putting main program into wait state. You can use it to parallelize for loop as well. When called for a for loop, though loop is sequential but every iteration runs in parallel to the main program as soon as interpreter gets there.

For your case you can do:

```
import asyncio
import time
from itertools import product


def background(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(None, f, *args, **kwargs)                                   
    return wrapped
    
@background
def call_fortran_program(a, b, c):
    time.sleep(max(0,b-a+c)) # Added Sleep to better demonstrate parallelization
    print(f"function called for {a=}, {b=}, {c=}\n", end='')
    return (a, b, c)

a_range, b_range, c_range = range(1,4), range(1,4), range(1,4)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()          # Have a new event loop

looper = asyncio.gather(*[call_fortran_program(a, b, c) for a in a_range for b in b_range for c in c_range])                   # Run the loop
                             
result_list = loop.run_until_complete(looper) # Wait until finish

print(result_list)
```

This gives following output:

```
function called for a=1, b=1, c=1
function called for a=1, b=2, c=1
function called for a=1, b=1, c=2
function called for a=2, b=1, c=1
function called for a=1, b=3, c=1
function called for a=1, b=2, c=2
function called for a=1, b=1, c=3
function called for a=2, b=1, c=2
function called for a=1, b=3, c=2
function called for a=1, b=2, c=3
function called for a=2, b=1, c=3
function called for a=2, b=2, c=1
function called for a=3, b=1, c=1
function called for a=3, b=1, c=2
function called for a=3, b=2, c=1
function called for a=2, b=2, c=2
function called for a=2, b=3, c=1
function called for a=3, b=2, c=2
function called for a=3, b=1, c=3
function called for a=2, b=2, c=3
function called for a=1, b=3, c=3
function called for a=3, b=3, c=1
function called for a=2, b=3, c=2
function called for a=3, b=2, c=3
function called for a=3, b=3, c=2
function called for a=2, b=3, c=3
function called for a=3, b=3, c=3
[(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 1), (1, 3, 2), (1, 3, 3), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 3), (2, 3, 1), (2, 3, 2), (2, 3, 3), (3, 1, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 1, 3), (3, 2, 1), (3, 2, 2), (3, 2, 3), (3, 3, 1), (3, 3, 2), (3, 3, 3)]
```