# Easiest (least amount of boilerplate code) way to parallelize a python loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-3.7

I have some code that looks like this:

```
for photo in photoInfo:
    if not('url' in photo):
        raise Exception("Missing URL: " + str(photo) + " in " + str(photoInfo))
    sizes = getImageSizes(photo['url'])
    photo.update(sizes)
```

It might not be obvious, but the code performs a mix of high-latency I/O (opening a remote URL) and moderately CPU-intensive process (parsing image and extracting size) for each photo.

What's the easiest way to parallelize this code?

**What I have tried so far**

I found this code in the answer to another, [more complex question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37929315/parallelize-python-for-loop), but I'm having a hard time mapping it back to my much simpler use-case:

```
from itertools import product
from multiprocessing import Pool

with Pool(processes=4) as pool:  # assuming Python 3
    pool.starmap(print, product(range(2), range(3), range(4)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Pool.map` to parallelize the fetching of image sizes, and build a new dict with the returning values and the same keys:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def get_image_size(photo):
    if 'url' not in photo:
        raise Exception("Missing URL: " + str(photo))
    return getImageSizes(photo['url'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool() as pool:
        photoInfo = dict(zip(photoInfo, pool.map(get_image_size, photoInfo)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os

def user_defined_function(url):
    #your logic for a single url
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    urls_list = ['u1','u2']
    pool = Pool(os.cpu_count())                         # Create a multiprocessing pool
    pool.map(user_defined_function, urls_list)
```

it's sample code you can modify it according to your usage. I will map each element of the list to your function and perform it individually.